Snakemake Cluster submission: log files are deleted while job is running if they are rule output
I have a rule B that is dependent on the log files a previous rule A created. These log files are created by the cluster that I am submitting to (HTCondor). These logs contain information that the cluster scheduler is collecting, such as memory usage, disk usage runtime etc. My group is using some scripts to evaluate this "metadata" and I have another rule that is supposed to run these scripts.
Now to the issue I am experiencing. The .log file is created by the cluster as soon as the job is submitted, but before the job itself actually starts. Now a few seconds later the job A starts and immediately deletes the .log file, since rules remove their output before recreating it. This causes the rule to fail, since the .log will not be recreated (and in any case, at this point information that I need is already lost).
My desired behaviour would result in the .log existing after the rule is done, and old instances of it being deleted BEFORE the job submission starts so that it only ever contains the log of a single job submission. For the .out file this works, because the cluster only creates this after the job has finished.
rule A:
    input:
        input.file
    output:
        output.file
        rule_A.log
        rule_A.out
rule B:
   input:
        rule_A.log

I do not know how to get the desired behaviour, is there any way to do this with snakemake? An option that would allow me to define outputs that should not be deleted before execution would be ideal.
I tried also to put rule_A.log in the log section of rule A, but this shows the same behaviour.
EDIT:
A minimal example of this looks like this:
rule make_files:
    input:
        input_file.dat
    output:
        output_file.dat
        condor_logs.log
    shell: 
        """
        source script {input}
        """

The script simply takes an input file, does some operations on it and creates an output file. Critically, it does NOT explicitly produce condor_logs.log. This file is produced by the cluster the moment the job goes into the queue, which is before snakemake actually starts executing the rule.

You could try using the protected() flag. Docs: https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#protected-and-temporary-files

Unfortunately, this doesn't make a difference. As the documentation states: "A protected file will be write-protected after the rule that produces it is completed." But my .log file gets deleted before the rule is completed.

Can you share a reproducible example? Or your actual rule A? I made this which I think recreates your scenario:
def create_log_file(wc):
    with open("a.log", "w") as f:
        f.write("hello world")
    return []


rule all:
    input:
        "b.out",


rule a:
    input:
        create_log_file, # simulate writing log file before execution
    output:
        out="a.out",
        log="a.log",
    shell:
        """
        echo a > {output.out}
        """


rule b:
    input:
        rules.a.output.log,
    output:
        "b.out",
    shell:
        "cat {input} > {output}"


This runs, and b.out has "hello world" in it.

I do not think this is actually reproducing my issue. In your example it is snakemake itself that creates A.log, whereas in my case this file is written by the cluster submission manager and is thus already present when snakemake starts up. Snakemake then cleans up this file, because it thinks it is output from a previous run. That needs to be deleted and redone.
I will try to come up with a minimal example though.
